# Get date of previous and next week monday from a particular date

Tags: java, android, date

I have current week Monday's date with me. Now I would like to find date of previous week Monday if I click on previous and next Monday if I click on next in java. I am looking for a way to add seven days to my date.

Comment: You haven't post your code so answer is general.   
  
Why you can't just subtract or add to current Monday 7 days (1 week)? In which format are you storing the date?

Comment: i can do that but its just not 1 previous or 1 next ...i want to go multiple previous and multiple next then ?

Comment: If you want go ahead, you can just increase days shift counter by `7`. If it equals `0` - that means "no shift" i.e. current Monday. If it `-7` - prev Monday, if '-14' - two Mondays before.

Comment: erm ... `theday.plusDays(7)` ... `theday.minusDays(7)` ... or are you on an old version of Java?

Comment: [Search StackOverflow](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+next+monday&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for *many* Questions and Answers on this topic. Please search before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use calendar class for this:
Here is the example

```
String dt = "2015-04-13";  // Current monday date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
if(next){
  c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  // for next Monday
}else{ 
  c.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);  // for previous Monday
}
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2015, Calendar.April, 15);//Given date
System.out.printf("Starting day ", calendar);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);//for next
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);//for previous
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String date = "2015-04-13";  // Current Monday date.

    System.out.println(process(date, "next"));
    System.out.println(process(date, "PREVIOUS"));
    System.out.println(process(date, "next"));
}

private static String process(String date, String operation)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //create new calendar instance
    calendar.clear(); //clear the current information on the calendar instance
    calendar.setLenient(false);

    try {
        calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date)); //parse current Monday date and set as calendar date/time
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if("NEXT".equalsIgnoreCase(operation)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  // for next Monday
    }

    if("PREVIOUS".equalsIgnoreCase(operation)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);  // for previous Monday
    }

    return sdf.format(calendar.getTime()); //format the calendar date/time
}
```